# lock/unlock screen using sensor ( like normal calls or messenger calls )

Tags: flutter, proximitysensor

i need to lock and unlock device ( turning screen off and on like phone calls when the phone is close to your ear) .

- i used proximity_plugin for proximity sensor listener but i can't find a way to turn off the screen
- i used a black screen and full screen mode but i don't like this solution i need to make it same as phone calls ( what am i missing ? )

```
    proximityEvents.listen((ProximityEvent event) async{
      if(event.x == 'Yes'){
        //enter full screen
        SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
        //show black screen
        setState(() {
          isLocked = true;
        });
      }else {
        //exit full screen
        SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);
        //w8 150 mili sec then remove black screen
        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 150), () {
          setState(() {
            isLocked = false;
          });
        });
      }

    });
```